# Is it clean to place method for comparing 2 objects of same class into that class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, groovy

Let's say I have class `Car` (just for illustration)

```
class Car {
   ...
   boolean isRed();
   ...
}
```

where to place methods which acts with objects of same class, in my example Car, but not just on that single instance of Car, rather on more - let's say 2 instances of same class (look following example).

`boolean haveCarsSameColor(Car a, Car, b);`

generally, what is the good place for such methods? is it class `Car`?

Comment: What do you mean by "good?"

Comment: Is the color of the car exposed as a property?

Comment: maybe I just oversimplified the example. Imagine there is more difficult operation behind getting the value of that `haveCarsSameColor`, the main point is if it should be in class Car or somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generally-accepted idiom for such methods in Java is based on the Java Object `equals()` method, which accepts a different object for comparison:

> `public boolean equals(Object obj)`
>
> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

Ergo:

```
public bool IsSameColorAs(car other) {
    return this.color == other.color;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool IsSameColor = car1.IsSameColorAs(car2);
```

Comment: that seems clearly to me, and if it's generally accepted idiom, I will use it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Single Responsibility Principle says that a class contains the logic pertaining to that class.

My take is that colors define what "Same" means, so the logic to test if two colors are "the same" would be implemented in your color class/struct, or an extension method for the color.

For example:

```
car1.Color.IsSameAs(car2.Color);
```

That also allows you to determine if two colors are too close for your application's purposes to tell apart they would still be considered the "same".

In C# you can use Extension methods to add functions for a class or struct you did not create.  Here is an example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsSameAs(this Color thisColor, Color otherColor)
    {
        return Math.Abs(thisColor.R - otherColor.R + thisColor.G - otherColor.G + thisColor.B - otherColor.B) < 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `thisColor.R - otherColor.R + thisColor.G - otherColor.G + thisColor.B - otherColor.B` ... :|

Comment: Just an example to show that `IsSameAs` does not necessarily mean direct equality in all cases.  There's a range of colors that users will perceive as the same.  Similar concepts apply when you are dealing with comparing time.

Comment: Oh i see. Fair enough!